# Loop over multiple lists in netbox_device in Ansible

Tags: list, loops, ansible

My goal is to create new devices in NetBox with ansible. So, I use netbox_device for this reason. I am getting the required information (device names, types, serial numbers etc) from a json file like the following one:

```
{
"results":{
       "infos": [
            {
                "device_type": "type1",
                "device_name": "name1",
                "serial_number": "num1"
            },
            {
                "device_type": "type2",
                "device_name": "name2",
                "serial_number": "num2"
            }

        ]

}
```

}

So, what I am doing is that I have this simple task to create 1 new device :

```
- name: Create new devices within Netbox 
  netbox_device:
    netbox_url: http://url.goes.here
    netbox_token: 7575747448..66353
    data:
      name: name1
      device_type: type1
      device_role: Core Switch
      serial_number: "num1"
      site: Main
    state: present
```

This is something simple if someone wants to create one specific new device, but I want to dynamically create new devices while looping some lists with the required info.

In particular, I create from the json file one list with all devices names

```
ok: [localhost] => {
"ansible_facts": {
    "dev_names": [
        "nameisone", 
        "nameistwo"
    ]
}, 
"changed": false
```

}

Then I create another list from the json file with the device types

```
ok: [localhost] => {
"ansible_facts": {
    "dev_types": [
        "type_one", 
        "type_two"
    ]
}, 
"changed": false
```

}

So now I have a task with 1 loop regarding the above lists:

```
 - name: Create new devices within Netbox looping the lists with the required info
  netbox_device:
    netbox_url: http://url.goes.here
    netbox_token: 754544444444404509504959433333333
    data:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      device_type: "{{ item }}"
      device_role: "Core Switch"
      site: Site 
      #serial_number: "number"
    state: present
  loop:
    - "{{ dev_names }}"
    - "{{ dev_types }} "
```

This works well only with one list, which means that if I comment out one of the two lists I get no errors.

The error I am getting when I run this task with both my lists is this:

```
 File "/tmp/poioanni/ansible_netbox_device_payload_5W1o8U/ansible_netbox_device_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/net_tools/netbox/netbox_utils.py", line 352, in normalize_data
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

failed: [localhost] (item=[u'nameisone', u'nameistwo']) => {
"ansible_loop_var": "item",
"changed": false,
"item": [
"nameisone",
"nameistwo"
],

Any ideas ?

Comment: You have to [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) over `results.infos`. Have you tried ?

Comment: @Zeitounator I successfully loop over results.infos and get all the info and create my lists. How do I make this task to run for as many times as my new devices and create 1 new device each time with the information from my lists?

Comment: Relaunch the playbook with the new data.

Comment: @Zeitounator in particular instead of having 2 tasks , one task that is gonna create a new device with the data {name1, type1 and num1} and one task that is gonna create a new device with the data {name2, type2, num2} i want to have 1 task which is gonna loop my lists and create as many devices as they have. For example, 1 list has all the device_names {name1, name2} the other list has the {num1, num2} etc

Comment: This once again the description of a loop. What have you tried ? What is the problem your are facing ?

Comment: @Zeitounator how do i add a loop in the above task so as to get elements from my lists instead of manually writing the name , type etc in the `data:
      name: name1
      device_type: type1
      device_role: Core Switch
      serial_number: "num1"
      site: Main`

Comment: Your very first reply was `I successfully loop over results.infos`. So where is your problem exactly ? Did you actually click on the link I provided in my first comment ? And once you clicked did you actually read the provided documentation with all the examples ? And alternatively did you research and experiment on how to create a loop with ansible ? Please don't spread information all over comments. Edit your question with what you have tried and specify what is your exact problem when writing this loop.

Comment: @Zeitounator I edited my question with required info !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure your lists are synchronized, you can use the [`zip` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#zip-and-zip-longest-filters), as demonstrated in the below `test.yml` MVCE playbook.

```yaml
---
- name: Zip demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    "dev_names": [
      "nameisone",
      "nameistwo"
    ]

    "dev_types": [
      "type_one",
      "type_two"
    ]

  tasks:
    - name: demonstrate how to use the zip filter with a loop
      debug:
        msg: "Element from first list: {{ item.0 }}. Element from second list: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ dev_names | zip(dev_types) | list }}"
```

Which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [Zip demo] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [demonstrate how to use the zip filter with a loop] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['nameisone', 'type_one']) => {
    "msg": "Element from first list: nameisone. Element from second list: type_one"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['nameistwo', 'type_two']) => {
    "msg": "Element from first list: nameistwo. Element from second list: type_two"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```